# Find the image of the sector $|z|\lt 1, 0\lt \arg z\lt \frac{\pi}{n}$, for the function $w=\frac{z^n+1}{z^n-1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Find the image of the sector $|z|\lt 1, 0\lt \arg z\lt \frac{\pi}{n}$, for the function $w=\frac{z^n+1}{z^n-1}$.

$w$ is a composite of two functions $\phi_1=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ and $\phi_2z^n$, and since $z^n$ maps onto the upper semicircle, I need to determine the image of the interior of this semicircle under $\phi_1$.

I know that this function is a fractional linear map so it maps circles onto circles or lines, but in this case it is a semicircle. I'm stuck here on how to proceed. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: After applying $\phi_2$, you have the intersection of the unit disk with the upper half-plane. Where does $\phi_1$ map the unit disk, and where does it map the upper half-plane?

Comment: @DanielFischer What I got is $\phi_1$ maps the unit disk to the imaginary axis, and the upper half-plane to the lower half-plane. So the image of the interior of the circle should be the left half-lane, and so we should get the third quadrant as the image, but the answer says upper half-plane. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: You mean that $\phi_1$ maps the unit _circle_ to the imaginary axis, I suppose. Okay, which half-plane is the unit disk mapped to, left or right?

Comment: The left since the image of $0$ is negative real.

Comment: Right, and indeed the image is the third quadrant. So if you did something wrong, it would have been a mistake in copying the function resp. its domain. If you haven't made a mistake there, the answer sheet is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, one last question. Then the image of the square of this function should be the lower half plane?

Comment: No, $w \mapsto w^2$ maps the third quadrant to the upper half-plane.

Comment: I'm really confused...Why is that?

Comment: $re^{i\varphi} \mapsto r^2 e^{2i\varphi}$. For $\pi < \varphi < \frac{3\pi}{2}$, we have $2\pi < 2\varphi < 3 \pi$, and these arguments put you in the upper half-plane.